Unable to launch system update screen in settings using "android.settings.SYSTEM_UPDATE_SETTINGS" intent action
I want to launch the system update screen of settings in my android devices from my app.
I saw that android.settings.SYSTEM_UPDATE_SETTINGS intent action is responsible for doing that but my app crashes with ActivityNotFoundException when I try to start activity with this intent.
I then accessed google developers official documentation for the settings class and found that this intent action no more exists in that class.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings
Does this mean google has restricted apps to now launch the system update screen or is there something new introduced in order to achieve that?
I tried using the below intent action to launch the system update screen.
/**
     * Activity Action: Show settings for system update functionality.
     * <p>
     * In some cases, a matching Activity may not exist, so ensure you
     * safeguard against this.
     * <p>
     * Input: Nothing.
     * <p>
     * Output: Nothing.
     *
     * @hide
     */
    @SdkConstant(SdkConstantType.ACTIVITY_INTENT_ACTION)
    public static final String ACTION_SYSTEM_UPDATE_SETTINGS =
            "android.settings.SYSTEM_UPDATE_SETTINGS";


According to the doc

In some cases, a matching Activity may not exist, so ensure you
safeguard against this.

So the only thing you can do is checking if there is an activity which can handle your intent with the specified action. Use the snippet:
public Boolean areSettingsAvailable(Context context, Intent intent) {
List<ResolveInfo>
    activities = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
return activities != null && activities.size() > 0; }

